# PowerBI Desktop returning 404 getting OData API but works fine in Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, odata, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a customers OData feed that I want to pull into PowerBI. When calling the API directly PowerBI works fine using a bearer token

i.e https://api.mywebsite.com/odata/customers

However I route all my traffic through a reverse proxy (a basic url rewrite in the web.config) so all requests actually come through this url:

https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/odata/customers

This reverse proxy url works fine in Fiddler. It reroutes to the first url and also works does this correctly when my UI calls it in the browser. However PowerBI returns a 404 everytime.

I enabled PowerBI trace logs and found 2 errors appearing

```
"https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/odata/customers"
ExceptionType: System.Net.WebExceptionPublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\r\n
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
StackTrace:\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   
at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Common.WrappingHttpWebRequest


Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataFallbackVersionHandler.
HandleVersionFallbackMessage:
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
 127.0.0.1:8888
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect
```

I checked my reverse proxy and web app logs and there are no 404s which suggests its a genuine 404 in the error above, but not sure what the 127.0.0.1 error means?

There are no firewall restrictions on my reverse proxy url as Fiddler works fine to make the call from my local machine. Just PowerBI does not like it, however PowerBI works fine with the direct call to the API. I have tried clearing all the data source permissions in PowerBI to start from scratch, but I am using bearer token auth in the headers anyway so they should not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out I was using OData v3 and the server had OData v4, now its backward compatible but you have to add MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" to the headers on your request out from PowerBI. PowerBI itself did not let me capture data and inspect through fiddler, however Excel did on the same API.